# Implemented Singly Linked List in C++

Tags: c++, beginner, linked-list

I have re-implemented Singly Linked List based on previous [review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/182779/implementing-singly-linked-list-using-c)
on this website. I have added iterators and remove mistakes. I did not use template classes because I have not learned about them yet.

### SinglyList.hpp

```
#ifndef SINGLYLIST_HPP
#define SINGLYLIST_HPP

class Iterator;

class SinglyList
{
private:
    struct Node { int data; Node *next; };
    Node *head;
public:
    SinglyList();                                                  //constructor
    ~SinglyList();                                                 //distructor
    SinglyList(const SinglyList& rhs);                             //copy constructor
    SinglyList& operator=(const SinglyList& rhs);                  //assignment overload
    bool empty();                                                  //check if list is empty
    int& front();                                                  //return refrence to first element
    void pop_back();                                               //pop last element
    void pop_front();                                              //pop first element
    unsigned int size();                                           //return size of list
    void remove(int value);                                        //remove passed value from list 
    bool search(int value);                                        //return true if passed value found and vice versa
    void push_back(int value);                                     //add an element at the end of list
    void push_front(int value);                                    //add an element at the start of list
    Iterator begin() const;                                        //begin iterator
    Iterator end() const;                                          //end iterator
    friend class Iterator;                                         //This class is friend of Iterator class
};

class Iterator 
{
private:
    SinglyList::Node *curr;
public:
    Iterator();                                                     //constructor
    Iterator(SinglyList::Node *rhs);                                //parameterized constructor 
    int& operator *() const;                                        //reference operator overload
    Iterator operator++ (int);                                      //post increment operator overload 
    bool operator!=(const Iterator& rhs);                           //not equal operator overload 
    Iterator& operator=(const Iterator& rhs);                       //assignment overload
    friend class SinglyList;                                        //This class is friend of SinglyList class
};
#endif // SINGLYLIST_HPP
```

### SinglyList.cpp

```
#include "SinglyList.hpp"

SinglyList::SinglyList()
{
    head = nullptr;
}

SinglyList::SinglyList(const SinglyList& rhs)
{
    Node *temp = rhs.head, *newer = new Node;
    head = newer;
    while (temp != nullptr)
    {
        newer->data = temp->data;
        temp = temp->next;
        if (temp != nullptr)
        {
            newer->next = new Node;
            newer = newer->next;
        }
        else
            newer->next = nullptr;
    }
}

SinglyList& SinglyList::operator=(const SinglyList& rhs)
{
    if(head != nullptr)
    {
        Node *prev = nullptr;
        while(head != nullptr)
        {
            prev = head;
            head = head->next;
            delete prev;
        }
    }
    Node *temp = rhs.head, *newer = new Node;
    head = newer;
    while (temp != nullptr)
    {
        newer->data = temp->data;
        temp = temp->next;
        if (temp != nullptr)
        {
            newer->next = new Node;
            newer = newer->next;
        }
        else
            newer->next = nullptr;
    }
    return *this;
}

SinglyList::~SinglyList()
{
    Node* prev = nullptr;
    while (head != nullptr)
    {
        prev = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete prev;
    }
}

bool SinglyList::empty()
{
    return head == nullptr;
}

int& SinglyList::front() 
{
    return head->data;
}

unsigned int SinglyList::size()
{
    Node* temp = head;
    unsigned int count = 0;
    while (temp != nullptr)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

void SinglyList::push_front(int value)
{
    Node* newer = new Node;
    newer->data = value;
    if (empty())
    {
        head = newer;
        newer->next = nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        newer->next = head;
        head = newer;
    }
}

void SinglyList::push_back(int value)
{
    Node* newer = new Node;
    newer->data = value;
    if (empty())
    {
        newer->next = nullptr;
        head = newer;
    }
    else
    {
        Node* temp = head;
        while (temp->next != nullptr)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        newer->next = nullptr;
        temp->next = newer;
    }
}

void SinglyList::remove(int value)
{
    if(!empty()) 
    {
        Node *temp = head, *prev = nullptr;
        if (temp->data == value)
            head = temp->next;
        else
        {
            while (temp->next != nullptr && temp->data != value)
            {
                prev = temp;
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            if (temp->data == value)
                prev->next = temp->next;
        }
        delete temp;
    }
}

bool SinglyList::search(int value)
{
    if (empty())
        return false;
    else
    {
        bool check = false;
        Node* temp = head;
        while (temp != nullptr)
        {
            if (temp->data == value)
            {
                check = true;
                break;
            }
            else
                temp = temp->next;
        }
        return check;
    }
}

void SinglyList::pop_front()
{
    Node* temp = head;
    head = temp->next;
    delete temp;
}

void SinglyList::pop_back()
{
    if(!empty())
    {
        Node *temp = head, *prev = nullptr;
        if (head->next == nullptr)
            head = temp->next;
        else
        {
            while (temp->next != nullptr)
            {
                prev = temp;
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            prev->next = nullptr;
        }
        delete temp;
    }
}

Iterator SinglyList::begin() const
{
    return Iterator(head);
}

Iterator SinglyList::end() const
{
    Node *temp = head;
    while(temp != nullptr)
    {
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    return Iterator(temp);
}

Iterator::Iterator() 
{
    curr = nullptr;
}

Iterator::Iterator(SinglyList::Node *rhs) 
{
    curr = rhs;
}

Iterator& Iterator::operator=(const Iterator& rhs) 
{
    curr = rhs.curr;
    return *this;
}

bool Iterator::operator !=(const Iterator& rhs)  
{
    return curr != rhs.curr;
}

int& Iterator::operator *() const
{
    return curr->data;
}

Iterator Iterator::operator ++(int)
{
    curr = curr->next;
    return *this;
}
```

### main.cpp

```
#include "SinglyList.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    SinglyList l1;
    l1.push_back(11);
    l1.push_front(10);
    l1.push_front(9);
    l1.push_front(8);

    Iterator it;
    for(it = l1.begin(); it != l1.end(); it++) 
    {
        std::cout << *it << " ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Note that it's 'destructor', not 'distructor'.

Comment: Not worth a full answer, but I would put the more trivial functions inside the definition of your class, in the header file. That will allow the compiler to inline that code. For example, your constructor is a single statement. Writing it inline would make that function relatively much less work to type (2 lines of code in 1 file rather than 3 lines in 2 files) and on top of that potentially speeds up execution.

Answer (score 6):

A few thoughts:

### Class naming

It's more important to know what an object *does* than to know the details of its implementation. Knowing that `SinglyList` is a type of "list" and that it can only be traversed easily in one direction are sometimes interesting to know, but `IntegerList` would be better (because it says what this is a list *of*).
If you wanted to be more specific about the way the list works,
you could call it `ForwardIntegerList` or `IntegerForwardList`;
"Singly" is only an indirect way of implying "traversed more easily in one direction," whereas "Forward" describes that property more directly and also reminds us which direction is easier.

But I see you also have a class named `Iterator`--not `SinglyList::Iterator`, not `SinglyListIterator`, but just `Iterator`. Do you never intend to put this in any program with any other class that might need to be iterated over? This class should have a more specific name.

### const functions

You should declare your functions `const` where you can.
In particular `empty`, `size`, and `search` would typically be declared
`bool empty() const`, `unsigned int size() const`,
and `bool search(int value) const`.
Not only is this a good reminder to you about whether it is safe to call
a particular function when you don't want to modify the data structure,
you can pass a `const SinglyList&` parameter to a function which can then call these functions of `SinglyList`.

It can be useful to have a `const` version of the `front` function too,
but it should be declared `const int& front() const`
or `int front() const` so that it doesn't provide a way to modify the 
contents of the list.

For the same reasons, it's good to have `const` versions of the `begin` and `end` functions
(in fact, given how few ways one can access the interior of this list type,
not having `const` versions of these functions would cripple any object
passed as a `const SinglyList&`),
but the functions you have return an iterator *that can modify the contents of the list.*
That is *not* good: it makes the difference between a `SinglyList&` and a `const SinglyList&` practically meaningless.
A typical way to fix this is to have a "const iterator" class in addition to your `Iterator`, where the "const iterator" has read-only access to the list:
the `*` operator in the "const iterator" class would be
`const int& operator *() const` or `int operator *() const`.
(Compare `iterator` vs. `const_iterator` in STL; or maybe better still, look up the classes of the same names [in the Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html#begin), which I find  a little easier to navigate).

In any case, when `begin` and `end` return iterators that allow you to modify the list, those functions should not be `const`.

### Don't declare variables before you need to

Consider this piece of code from `SinglyList::operator =`, for example:

```
    if(head != nullptr)
    {
        Node *prev = nullptr;
        while(head != nullptr)
        {
            prev = head;
            head = head->next;
            delete prev;
        }
    }
```

Instead, you could write

```
    if(head != nullptr)
    {
        while(head != nullptr)
        {
            Node *prev = head;
            head = head->next;
            delete prev;
        }
    }
```

There is no advantage whatsoever to declaring `prev` earlier than that; the first version of the code is more complicated and will not run any faster than the second version.

### An empty list is not as special as you think

In several of your functions you treat an empty list as a special case
that has to be checked before the code for the more general case can begin.
In most places where you do this, it is not needed.
For example, consider this piece of code in `SinglyList::operator =` again:

```
    if(head != nullptr)
    {
        Node *prev = nullptr;
        while(head != nullptr)
        {
            prev = head;
            head = head->next;
            delete prev;
        }
    }
```

You could replace *this entire block of code* with this:

```
    while(head != nullptr)
    {
        Node *prev = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete prev;
    }
```

What happens if you happen to pass an empty list into this function?
Then `head` will be equal to `nullptr` when this block of code executes;
the `while` condition will be false before the very first iteration,
and the entire block of code will do *nothing* to the list--exactly the
same as the more complicated `if` block would have.
The only thing that is accomplished by putting the `while` inside an `if` is to hint to the compiler that it should compare the head of the list to `nullptr` twice. (I say "hint" because an optimizing compiler could very well decide to compile the two examples exactly the same; it can ignore your hint.)

Similarly, you could rewrite `push_front` like this:

```
void SinglyList::push_front(int value)
{
    Node* newer = new Node;
    newer->data = value;
    newer->next = head;
    head = newer;
}
```

What happens if you pass an empty list to this function? Then `head` will be equal to `nullptr` when the function is called, and `newer->next = head;` will set `newer->next` to `nullptr`, exactly as your version of this function does.

You can simplify `push_back` and `search` in similar ways.

### Avoid duplication of code

There are two places in the definition of `SinglyList` where you have to remove all nodes from a list: `operator =` and the destructor.
There are two places where you have to copy all the nodes from one list to another: `operator =` and the copy constructor.
You could write a function for each of those tasks,
and call those functions instead of making copies of their implementations.
The function for removing all nodes would be like the `clear` function of STL containers, and might be useful to make public;
but I would recommend that you make the copying function private, since calling it on an object that is not empty would cause a memory leak.